# This out put is confusing me

Tags: html, css, width

Short description: I strip down the code, this is not my original code, but with this code i can recreate the problem, i was thinking i will be able to solve the problem and in the end i did, solution make sense but it also confuse me, means why i have to use it.

> Edit1- Description -The thing is when their are two field label and input are at same line, but as i soon as i delete one of the div label and input are at different linee, it should not happened as div width is 50%

Please read the qoute before html code, and you will be able to understand the problem, explaining it bit difficult.

> in html code, just i have three div inside form, just remove one of the div and run the code you will understand why i am confused about it.

I was able to solve the problem by giving width to my div class form, that's fine but i am confused why i have to do it, Thanks

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.form form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form div {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  min-width: 45%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="form">

    <form>

      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>password</label>
        <input type="password">
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what is your confusion.

Comment: @ramprasadagarwal The thing is when their are two field label and input are at same line, but as i soon as i delete one of the div label and input are at different linee, it should not happened as div width is 50%

Comment: for me, after deleting one div from three divs. I am getting two input fields in the same line.

Comment: @ramprasadagarwal what about label

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS will put all div's in same line even if you delete one of the div label/input.

For `form div`, added `display: inline-flex, padding: 2px;` and for `input`, added `margin-left: 4px;`. Hope this is what you want.

```
form div {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  min-width: 45%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the responde, i can solve it by giving a width of 100% to my form class what i really want, i want to know why